How to disable api key requirement on AWS API Gateway through OpenAPI/Swagger schema?
I have this OpenAPI schema that's used by terraform to construct my API Gateway. Because I'm setting security: [] on /v2/bar, I'm expecting the api key requirement to be disabled for that specific endpoint. However on AWS console it's still enabled:

x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: HEADER
security:
  - ApiKeyAuth: []
paths:
  /v2/foo:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: default
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: http
        httpMethod: GET
        uri: /v2/foo
        responses: {}
      responses: {}
  /v2/bar:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: default
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: http
        httpMethod: GET
        uri: /v2/bar
        responses: {}
      responses: {}
      security: []
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: x-api-key

I've tried countless things:

moving x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: HEADER to ApiKeyAuth
using security: [{}]
using x-amazon-apigateway-auth: type: NONE
...

The only thing that worked is removing security globally and setting it for each endpoint separately like so:
paths:
  /v2/foo:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: default
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: http
        httpMethod: GET
        uri: /v2/foo
        responses: {}
      responses: {}
      security:
        - ApiKeyAuth: []
  /v2/bar:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: default
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: http
        httpMethod: GET
        uri: /v2/bar
        responses: {}
      responses: {}
      security: []
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: x-api-key
      x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: HEADER

This is a simplified example. However, in my real use case I have 100+ endpoints of which only 1 needs to be publicly accessible. It's tedious to configure security for each endpoint.
Is there a way to disable api key requirement for a single endpoint?
